# Can I call a jython script from java -jar myjar.jar?

Tags: java, python, jar, jython, launch

I have a python script that I believe I can convert to jython. I want to call java -jar myjar.jar to launch my application. Is it possible to call that command, and have the main class call that script (does it have to be converted to jython)? The script launches my program. Let me know, it might sound a little roundabout, but it could save a ton of development time and deliver a solution for the short-term.

Comment: related: http://mavenjython.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a jar base on you Jython

http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/DistributingJythonScripts